# How to change text color using javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript

**When someone click on the text it change to red color and click on the other text return to black color.
I have make an example like below but how to make it shorter using for loop?**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>My little test page</title>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <div id="myid">Hello Here !!</div><br>
        <div id="myid2">Hello There !!</div><br>
        <div id="myid3">Hello !!</div><br>
        ......many div......
    </body>
    </html>

    <script language="javascript">
    function changeColor1() {
    document.getElementById("myid").className = "red";
    document.getElementById("myid2").className = "";
    document.getElementById("myid3").className = "";
    }

    function changeColor2() {
    document.getElementById("myid").className = "";
    document.getElementById("myid2").className = "red";
    document.getElementById("myid3").className = "";
    }

    function changeColor3() {
    document.getElementById("myid").className = "";
    document.getElementById("myid2").className = "";
    document.getElementById("myid3").className = "red";
    }

    function init() {
    document.getElementById("myid").onclick = changeColor1;
    document.getElementById("myid2").onclick = changeColor2;
    document.getElementById("myid3").onclick = changeColor3;
    }

    window.onload = init();
    </script>
```

Comment: Should just the color of the current text change, or do you want  a class named 'red' applied to it ?
The code above changes the class, but there is no styling info, so it will be invisible as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an attribute name to all the divs, like this

```
<div id='myid' name='colorchangingdiv[]'>Hello</div>
<div id='myid2' name='colorchangingdiv[]'>Hello</div>
....
```

Now in your init function

```
function init() {
var allDivs = document.getElementsByName('colorchangingdivs[]');

    for( var i =0; i < allDivs.length; ++i )
    {
       allDivs[i].onClick = changeColor(this);
    }
}
```

In your change color function

```
function changeColor( obj )
{
    var allDivs = document.getElementsByName('colorchangingdivs[]');

    for( var i =0; i < allDivs.length; ++i )
    {
       allDivs[i].style.color = '';
    }

    // Now set the color to the obj passed
    obj.style.color = 'red';
 }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>My little test page</title>
        </head>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
      <script language="javascript">
     $(".divid").click(function(e){
         $(".divid").css('color', '');
         $(this).css('color', 'red');

       });
       </script>
 <body id="body">
 <div id="myid" class="divid">Hello Here !!</div><br>
 <div id="myid2" class="divid">Hello There !!</div><br>
 <div id="myid3" class="divid">Hello !!</div><br>
 ......many div......
 </body>
 </html>
```

Example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JG2eU/)

Comment: he asked how to do that in a loop

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .red{
  color:red;
 }
</style>
<title>My little test page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
<script language="javascript">
  //use jquery for change your color
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".myclass").click(function(){
    $(".myclass").removeClass("red");
    $(this).addClass("red");
   });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <div class="myclass">Hello Here !!</div><br>
    <div class="myclass">Hello There !!</div><br>
    <div class="myclass">Hello !!</div><br>
    ......many div......
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, use classes instead of, or in addition to the id attributes of the div tags above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My little test page</title>
   </head>
   <body id="body">
      <div class="mytext">Hello Here !!</div><br>
      <div class="mytext">Hello There !!</div><br>
      <div class="mytext">Hello !!</div><br>

      <script>
        var myselector = 'div.mytext';
        function changeColor( e ){
          var x=document.querySelectorAll(myselector);
          for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            x[i].style.color = '';
          }
          e.target.style.color = 'red';
        }      
        function init(){
          var x=document.querySelectorAll(myselector);
          for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            x[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
              changeColor(e);
            });
          }
        }
        window.onload = init();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```